# Looping through a pickle dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, pickle

I am trying to load data from a pickle object/file however I can't seem to get rid of an error.

I have tried to set up a trace to ensure that my dictionary is populated with the data from the pickle file.

```py
fr = open(line, 'rb')
    dictionary = pickle.load(fr)
...
for key, value in dictionary.items()
```

I expected it to be able to loop through the dictionary but I continue to get the error: 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'.

I have tried:

```py
for key in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
```

but it did not solve the error.

Edit:
sys.version returns 3.7.3.

I have tried using:

```py
for key in dictionary:
```

This returns my data as the key:
['Head', '-0.02845094', '0.7953885', '2.586351']
However that returns a new error at run time:

```py
walk[key] = []
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Should I extract my data from the key or is there an easier way out of this?

Comment: Please identify your Python version.

Comment: Whenever you run into an issue like this, print out the thing that doesn't have the attribute you expected it to, as well as its type, before you try to use it: `print(dictionary, type(dictionary))`, and run your code again. Should help you understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to do but in your case its just because your `pickle.load` returns a list and you are trying to access the `.items` function of a list (wich doesn't exists, items is for dictionary).

You might want to try :

```py
for i in dictionary: # i is the name I usualy use here, its stands for Item but its way shorter and less painfull to type
    # your loop
```

I'm not sure if that the result you expect but at least it should run.